# Modify a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify the color attribute that is returned in JQuery. So, lets assume the color is returned and is contained in a

```
var color
color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124)'
```

I want to modify the value of color to be:

```
color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124, .7)'
```

(in other words, insert the string ", .7")

Comment: Just make the first tag like this `color = 'rgba(148, 141, 124,1)'` that will do the work easy for the next line..  `color = 'rgba(148, 141, 124,.7)'` just change last value from `1` to `.7` :) and make sure RGB and RGBA are different only RGB works in some browser but some browser might not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
color = color.replace(/\)/, ', 0.7)')
```

Comment: Yes,I am curious too.What's wrong with this expression?

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
var color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124)';
var newColor = color.slice(0,-1) + ",.7)"
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5m2bk/)

If you want it to be rgba then use,

```
var color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124)';
var newColor = (color.slice(0,-1) + ",.7)").split('(').join('a(');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5m2bk/1/)

Comment: It still needs the `a` in the `rgba`. OP forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above, slightly different method:

```
var color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124)';
var colorAlpha = color.replace(/rgb/g, 'rgba').replace(/\)/g, ', 0.7)');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aECVt/)

OR, as someone commented on the above, it could be simpler to add the alpha to the original variable, and just replace that number in the new string:

```
var color = 'rgba(148, 141, 124, 1.0)';
var colorAlpha = color.replace(/1.0/g, '0.7');
alert(colorAlpha);
```

Comment: I guess I just wanted to temp the mysterious Captain Downvote. Success!

Answer (score 0):

Using `.split()` also you can easily achieve your goal

```
var color = 'rgb(148, 141, 124)';
var newColor = color.split(")")[0];

alert(newColor + ', 0.7)');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5m2bk/4/)